# Filter YTD entries on SharePoint lists

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter, financial

I'm looking to create a view with a filter in SharePoint 2007 to only display items from a particular financial year (starting this year).

I tried to create a column with a calculation and filter it: =Created>DATE(2012,6,1) but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For something this simple you don't need a calculated column - you just need to create a View with a filter.

Also - don't use DATE(2012,6,1) - just use the date in the appropriate format that matches your sites regional settings (e.g. "1/6/2012" for the UK, "6/1/2012" for the US"

Example :-

[image: SharePoint - View filter]

This will create 'static' views such as "2012-13 Financial Year","2013-14 Financial Year" - if you want dynamic views such as "Current Financial Year", "Previous Finanical Year" then its a bit more complex so adapt this method for [filtering items in the current calendar month.](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/)